# CSS Flexbox -width breaking when container has more children

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to plot a set of equal sized color boxes on a div with span tags. I've used display: flex to achieve the same on parent.

```
<div style="width: 90%; height: 30px; border: blue solid 1px;">
    <div  style="display: flex; height:100%;">
        <!-- ng-repeat to generate random colors array of large size -->
        <span style="flex:1;" ng-repeat="healthValue in $ctrl.colors track by $index" ng-style="{'background-color': healthValue}">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a stackblitz link to a running sample: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-large-sizes-issue

[image]

However, I notice that when children count increases the flex seems to be breaking the widths of child elements. I assume this is because it's rounding off the child width calculation after a certain point. Can someone help me with overcoming this issue.

Comment: consider a min-width .. for example `min-width:3px`

Answer (score 2):

You have each `span` set to `width: 100%`. I assume that means 100% of the container, as percentage sizes on children are based on the parent size.

Then what you're looking for is `flex-shrink: 0` on the spans.

Flex items are set, by default, to `flex-shrink: 1`. This allows them to reduce their size in order to not overflow the container.

Comment: flex-shrink: 0; gives each span the width of parent. I want the parent width divided equally to all the child spans.

Comment: So why do you have each item set to `width: 100%`? Set them to `flex: 1` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it. But the issue still persists with flex-shrink:0; added as well.